# codewar challenge javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

I hope everyone is having a good day.

This is my first ever post on Stackoverflow!

I have just completed the javascript course on codeacademy and have read a couple of books on it too. Now I am on codewars. I would classify myself as a beginner in Javascript.

I find myslef a little stuck on a challenge, please can someone shed some light on what I may be doing wrong? Many thanks in advance!

Here is the instructions:

Check to see if a string has the same amount of 'x's and 'o's. The method must return a boolean and be case insensitive. The string can contains any char.

And here is my code:

```
function XO(str) {
    var x = [];
    var o = [];

    for (var i = 0; i <= str.length; i++) {
        if (str(i).toLowerCase === "x") {
            x.push(i);
        } else if (str(i).toLowerCase === "o") {
            o.push(i);
        }

        if (x.length === o.length) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Move your length check out of the for loop

Comment: your codes are not good format yet

Comment: why not use inbuilt string functions ?

Answer (score 1):

```
function XO(str) {
    var x = 0, // numbers are better
        o = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) { // changed from '<=' to '<'
        if (str[i].toLowerCase() === "x") {
            x++;
        } else if (str[i].toLowerCase() === "o") {
            o++;
        }
    }
    return x === o;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i corrected mistakes and use code comment to explain

```js
function XO(str) {
    var x = [];
    var o = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) { // i must be lower than length
        // str[i] or str.charAt(i), not str(i)
        if (str[i].toLowerCase() === 'x') { // toLowerCase is function, it must be called with toLowerCase()
            x.push(str[i]); // should push character
        } else if (str[i].toLowerCase() === 'o') {
            o.push(str[i]);
        }
    }
    // return statement must be located at the end
    if (x.length == o.length) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
console.log(XO('xo'));
console.log(XO('xxo'));
console.log(XO('xoX'));
console.log(XO('xoOX'));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, and thank you everyone else who responded. I just wanted to also ask, what is the difference if i used [i] instead of (i)...I know [i] works in a way to go through the index of arrays but I get a bit confused when people use it in the (i) method. I know this may be a sily question to many but as mentioned I am just starting out in javascript. Thanks guys

Comment: Parenthesis are used for method calling. Like ```str[i].toLowerCase()```. Here ```toLowerCase``` is a method. Angle brackets ```[]``` are used for accessing or changing the values in JSON or Array data objects. Both are totally different things.

Answer (score 0):

`str.match(/x/g).length==str.match(/o/g).length`

Answer (score 0):

The third if else will never be executed because for a string there will be always a value.

If you want to return the count then the check of length should be performed after the for loop.

```
var xCount = 0; var oCount = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i].toLowerCase() === "x") {
    xCount++;
  } else if (str[i].toLowerCase() === "o") {
    oCount++;
  }
}

return xCount === oCount;
```

About another solutions containing the check based on `str.match` method, the complexity of using that piece of code is twice compared to above because the `str.match` loop is performed twice to match both the strings.

Comment: This is the best answer since you only have to loop once.

Comment: the complexity is the same, if you loop once or twice. The number of instructions executed matters

Comment: As another answer already explained, there is another problem with `<= str.length`.

Comment: Sure but isn't the O time O(n) vs O(2n)?

Comment: You need to use `toLowerCase()` not `toLowerCase`, because the latter is a function code, while the former is the value that the function returns, in other words, `str(i).toLowerCase === "x"` is `true` for any character `str(i)`.

Comment: Thanks @MrGeek for pointing out the mistake. Thanks James for clarifying the complexity. Here in the above piece of code the complexity is the half of ```str.match``` based solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkIfOequalsX(str){
  return str.match(/x/g).length==str.match(/o/g).length
}

console.log(checkIfOequalsX('xxooxo'));
console.log(checkIfOequalsX('xxooxoo'));
```

you can do it with

```
str.match(/x/g).length==str.match(/o/g).length
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function XO(str) {
  let strn = str.toLowerCase();
  let countX = []; 
  let countO = []; 
  for(let i=0; i<strn.length; i++) {
    if(strn[i] == 'x') {
      countX.push(strn[i])
    } else if(strn[i] == 'o') {
      countO.push(strn[i])
    }
  }

  if(countX.length == countO.length){
    return true
  } else if(countX.length !== countO.length) {
    return false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Regex for finding those characters:

```
function XO(str) {
 return str.match(/o/ig).length === str.match(/x/ig).length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function XO(str) {
   let letraO = 0
   let letraX = 0
   const myArray = str.toLowerCase();
   for (i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
      myArray[i] === 'o'? letraO++ : letraX ++
   }
   return letraO===letraX? true : false    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function XO(str) {

    // make the string lowercase because we are case insensitive
    str = str.toLowerCase();

    // put the string into an array
    var arrayOfCharacters = str.split("");

    //count the x's
    var countX = arrayOfCharacters.reduce( function( n, val ) {
        return n + (val === 'x');
      }, 0);
      
    // count the o's
    var countO = arrayOfCharacters.reduce( function( n, val ) {
        return n + (val === 'o');
      }, 0);
    
    // do these numbers match? if so return true and if not return false
    if ( countX == countO ) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```